# PL/SQL how to display data from select statement inside procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am not sure how to display my select statement in my procedure. This is my code inside my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE numberOfSupplier (X INT:=0)
AS  
    rName REGION.R_NAME%TYPE;
    nName NATION.N_NAME%TYPE;
    sNKeyC SUPPLIER.S_NATIONKEY%TYPE;   
BEGIN
FOR rec IN(
    SELECT R.R_NAME, N.N_NAME, COUNT(S.S_NATIONKEY)
    INTO rName, nName, sNKeyC
    FROM REGION R, NATION N, SUPPLIER S
    WHERE R.R_REGIONKEY = N.N_REGIONKEY
    AND S.S_NATIONKEY = N.N_NATIONKEY
    GROUP BY R.R_NAME, N.N_NAME
    HAVING COUNT(S.S_NATIONKEY) > X)
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('R_NAME'||rName);
    dbms_output.put_line('N_NAME'||nName);
    dbms_output.put_line('COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)'||sNKeyC);
END LOOP;
END;
/ 

--executing numberOfSupplier
EXECUTE numberOfSupplier(130);
```

This is what I get, which has no errors but not what I want:

```
SQL> EXECUTE numberOfSupplier(130);
     R_NAME
     N_NAME
     COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)
     R_NAME
     N_NAME
     COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)
     R_NAME
     N_NAME
     COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)
     R_NAME
     N_NAME
     COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)
```

What I want to get is this:

```
    R_NAME            N_NAME            COUNT(S.S_NATIONKEY)
------------------------- ------------------------- --------------------
ASIA              INDONESIA                  131
ASIA              CHINA                      145
MIDDLE EAST       SAUDI ARABIA                   132
EUROPE            GERMANY                    132
```

I am able to get the above result if I just execute the select statement, however I dont know how to put this select statement in my procedure and get the table above:

```
SELECT R.R_NAME, N.N_NAME, COUNT(S.S_NATIONKEY)
FROM REGION R, NATION N, SUPPLIER S
WHERE R.R_REGIONKEY = N.N_REGIONKEY
AND S.S_NATIONKEY = N.N_NATIONKEY
GROUP BY R.R_NAME, N.N_NAME
HAVING COUNT(S.S_NATIONKEY) > 130;
```

Can someone explain to me why and how to fix this. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

Put headers out of the loop and then, in the loop, concatenate all values you'd want to display. Use `RPAD` to nicely align values.

Apart from that, you misused `FOR` loop; you don't select `INTO` within its `select` statement, but use cursor variable. I don't have your tables so I used Scott's, for illustration:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE numberOfSupplier (X INT:=0)
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4    dbms_output.put_line(rpad('R_NAME', 15, ' ') ||
  5                         rpad('N_NAME', 15, ' ') ||
  6                        'COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)'
  7                       );
  8    dbms_output.put_line(rpad('-', 14, '-') || ' ' ||
  9                         rpad('-', 14, '-') || ' ' ||
 10                         rpad('-', 14, '-'));
 11  FOR rec IN(
 12      SELECT d.dname R_NAME,
 13             e.ename N_NAME,
 14             COUNT(*) snkeyc
 15      FROM emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
 16      where e.deptno = 10
 17      group by d.dname, e.ename
 18     )
 19  loop
 20    dbms_output.put_line(rpad(rec.r_name, 15, ' ') ||
 21                         rpad(rec.n_name, 15, ' ') ||
 22                         rec.sNKeyC
 23                        );
 24  END LOOP;
 25  END;
 26  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec numberofsupplier;
R_NAME         N_NAME         COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)
-------------- -------------- --------------
ACCOUNTING     KING           1
ACCOUNTING     CLARK          1
ACCOUNTING     MILLER         1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, how do I show the COUNT of all the S_NATIONKEY in dbms_output.put_line ??

dbms_output.put_line(rpad(rec.R_NAME,15,' ')||
        rpad(rec.N_NAME,15,' ')||
        COUNT(rec.S_NATIONKEY));
give me error because it doesnt allow me to put COUNT

Comment: You have already fetched that count in select statement, so you'll have to display just REC.SNKEYC (just like I showed you). If you wanted to display "total count", then select it separately into a local variable and display that local variable in DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code slightly and using cursors instead must do your job.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE numberOfSupplier (X INT:=0)
AS
    CURSOR rec IS SELECT R.R_NAME, N.N_NAME, COUNT(S.S_NATIONKEY) counter
    FROM REGION R, NATION N, SUPPLIER S
    WHERE R.R_REGIONKEY = N.N_REGIONKEY
    AND S.S_NATIONKEY = N.N_NATIONKEY
    GROUP BY R.R_NAME, N.N_NAME
    HAVING COUNT(S.S_NATIONKEY) > X; -- cursor to collect all the Objects
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('R_NAME'||CHR(9)||'N_NAME'||CHR(9)||'COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)');
    dbms_output.put_line('--------------------------------------------------');
    FOR rec_obj IN rec LOOP  
        dbms_output.put_line(rec_obj.R_NAME||CHR(9)||CHR(9)||rec_obj.N_NAME||CHR(9)||CHR(9)||rec_obj.counter);
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin
    WHEN no_data_found THEN --catches exception when No Data Found
        dbms_output.put_line('No Data Found');
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN -- More than 1 row seleced
    dbms_output.put_line('More than 1 row seleced');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN  -- handles all other errors
        ROLLBACK;
        dbms_output.put_line('I AM HERE!!!'
                               || sqlcode
                               || ' '
                               || sqlerrm);
END;
/
```